# Convertir a for-loop

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo el siguiente recorrido de una matriz bidimencional:

```
EnsambleAsientos ea = new EnsambleAsientos(FilaNum);
    for (int f = 0; f < this.lineas.length; f++){
            for (int c = 0; c < this.lineas[f].length; c++) {
                if ((this.lineas[f][c].getId()).equals(FilaNum)){
                    ea = this.lineas[f][c];
                    break;
                }
            }
     }
```

pero NetBeans me suguiere hacer una conversión a "for-loop", para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
for (EnsambleAsientos[] linea : this.lineas) {
   for (EnsambleAsientos linea1 : linea) {
       if ((linea1.getId()).equals(FilaNum)) {
           ea = linea1;
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Qué beneficio encuentro al hacer la conversión? y ¿cómo funciona el for-loop?

Comment: El for-each es más elegante pero como es directamente con los valores del arreglo no tienes un iterador que te diga la posición, ten en cuenta que un compilador lo que trata es de refactorizar un código pero no mejorarlo, y a lo mucho te sugiere un cambio mas optimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el mensaje que te da es `Use enhanced for loop to iterate over the array`, te está recomendando usar el **enhanced loop** en español se traduce como `bucle mejorado`, pero es mas conocido como `for-each`, que se traduce como `por cada (o sea por cada elemento)`. No existe el `for loop`, creo que te confundiste con la palabra "for" del mensaje, creyendo que se trataba del bucle cuando en realidad dice "Utilice el bucle mejorado **para** iterar sobre la matriz" .
Te lo recomienda por que es un bucle "mejorado", que salió en la versión 5, cuyas 
principales ventajas son:

- no se necesita conocer la longitud de la lista (array, etc.)
- tampoco indicarle por donde comienza, sino que recorre la lista completa, "completa" 
  excepto si se usa el break
- no hace falta controlar índices

Pero las principales  desventajas son:

- No se puede usar para modificar o eliminar elementos (la más importante)
- poco control de indices, por ej. no podes incrementar un índice en determinado 
  momento

Comment: Ya revisé el mensaje y en efecto se trata de "Use enhanced for loop to iterate over the array", haré pruebas de éste "bucle mejorado" para usarlo en futuros proyectos.